# C pointer dereference error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, compiler-errors

Suppose I have the following code (example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void Ex(void *ret, int ret_len, int choice){
    if(choice==1){
        int *ret = ret;              
        for(int i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            *(ret+i) = i;
        }
     } else {
        int **ret = ret;            
        for(int i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<ret_len; j++){
                *(*(ret+i)+j) = i*j;
            }
        }
     }
}

int main()
{
    int m[10];
    Ex(m,10,1);
    printf("%i",m[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

The goal of the function is to take a pointer to preallocated memory of a one *or* two dimensional array.

When compiled and executed the code works when `choice==1`, otherwise, if I run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void Ex(void *ret, int ret_len, int choice){
    if(choice==1){
        int *ret = ret;              
        for(int i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            *(ret+i) = i;
        }
     } else {
        int **ret = ret;            
        for(int i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<ret_len; j++){
                *(*(ret+i)+j) = i*j;
            }
        }
     }
}

int main()
{
    int m[100];
    Ex(m,10,2);
    printf("%i", m[3][5]);
    return 0;
}
```

no output is ever produced and the code seems to run forever (note choice is now not 1 and m is the proper size)

I am under the impression that the casting in Ex should change the shape of the array and allow main to index into it as if it were 2d but neither indexing into it as if it were 1d nor 2d work.

Comment: type of `*(ret+i)` is `int`, So `*(int_value+j)` can't dereference.

Comment: Yup, this line `*(*(ret+i)+j)=i*j;` doesn't make sense.

Comment: The only difference between `ret[i][j]` and `*(*(ret+i)+j)` is that one is shorter and easier to read and harder to get wrong than the other — ***if*** the parameter type of `ret` is `int **ret` (or some variant on `int *ret[20]`).  With `ret` defined as `int *ret`, any double-dereferencing is wrong.  Note that the types `int **ret` and `int *ret[20]` are very different, even though you can use `ret[i][j]` with both.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That makes sense, but how can this be done in a conventional way?

Comment: Depending on how you secured with `malloc`, I think that it is necessary to compute a one-dimensional array as a two-dimensional array contrary to your explanation.

Comment: Please provide an actual [mcve] which means providing an example of the array allocation you intend to use here.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala done

Comment: @JonathanLeffler aren't `int **ret` and `int *ret[20]` convertible to each other? Do you mean int `(*ret)[20]`?

Comment: And now you added an aliasing error too... `float` and `int` are not compatible...

Comment: @CircArgs What? Now you have further messed it up! You are casting `float**` to `int**`

Comment: Also where exactly is `m` (or `_ret`) initialized? It is not a two dimensional array. It is an array of pointers.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I think i have fixed all the blatant errors

Comment: @CircArgs no, you haven't - `int **ret = ret;`? Even with different names it is wrong because `m` is `int[100]` and you are casting it to `int**`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Okay so now I think this is the heart of the problem here. The compiler didn't throw a warning or error so I assumed that cast was okay. If not as you say, can you suggest a solution to the problem in its entirety?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Split my comment into two halves — the first  about notation, the second about the type of `ret`.  The first half I stand by; I don't get the impression you disagree, but that's not important.  The second half I withdraw as I'm not confident it is correct and it's too late here to want to think about it.  The issue is that a 2D array is not the same as an array of pointers, even though the double-subscript notation can be used with both.  But I may have screwed up on choice of notation.

Comment: @CircArgs check the answer I just posted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 2D arrays are not the same as array of pointers - I totally agree. Probably the notation is not that important for this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at the comments on the question and some answers this is what I have gathered for your requirements.

You need a generic function that takes an array of `choice` dimensions and initializes it with some values.

This can suit your purpose.

```
void Ex(void *_ret, int ret_len, int choice){
    if(choice==1){
        int *ret = _ret;              
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            ret[i] = i;
        }
     } else {
        int (*ret)[ret_len] = _ret;            
        int i, j;
        for(i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            for(j=0; j<ret_len; j++){
                ret[i][j] = i*j;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Now this is how you can call it

```
int main(void) {
    int first[10];
    Ex(first, 10, 1);
    int second[20][20];
    Ex(second, 20, 2);
    printf("first[4] = %d\n", first[4]);
    printf("second[3][4] = %d\n", second[3][4]);
}
```

You can see the [Demo here](https://ideone.com/Xt12zr)

Comment: Your answer certainly works. Just a few questions if you don't mind and I'll accept. Is `int *ret = _ret; `  necessary? What is happening in `int (*ret)[ret_len] = _ret;`? Thanks for your help

Comment: `int *ret = _ret` is necessary because `_ret` is of type `void*` and you cannot dereference `void*` directly. Other way would have been to cast while using as `((int*)_ret)[i]`, but that is ugly, so I casted once into a separate variable.

Comment: As for `int (*ret)[ret_len]` it is defined as a *pointer to an array of int of size `ret_len`* which is what `int[ret_len][ret_len]` would also decay into. That is the correct way of dereferencing a variable declared originally as `int[20][20]`.

Comment: You might have seen `int ret**` also being used some where else but that is a *pointer to pointer of type int* and needs initialization with `malloc` (or non standard `alloc`) in a loop.

Comment: I'll have to read through it a few more times for it to click completely. Thanks. I've accepted your answer

Comment: If two dimensional array notations are confusing for you, you can create a single dimensional array of size `ret_len * ret_len` and the index into it as `ret[i * ret_len + j]`. Obviously your declaration will also change in that case. And since you mentioned that the arrays are not actually created by you but by some other code, you might stick to this. Infact the best option would be to "see" how they are declaring variables for 2 dimensions. Must be in the documentation somewhere.

Comment: This is another good point, yet what I think is most confusing me is the pointer syntax for example `(*ret)`. You say it is "pointer to an array of int of size `ret_len`" but did you mean an array of pointers to arrays of int[] of length `ret_len`?

Comment: @CircArgs no, The part inside the brackets is read first and hence it is a `pointer to`, next to read the stuff after the stuff on the right, `array of size ret_len` finally the type `int`. So *pointer to array of size ret_len*.

Answer (score 0):

because `ret` if of type `int *`, but the else part is:

```
    for(int i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<ret_len; j++){
            *(*(ret+i)+j)=i*j;
        }
    }
```

which needs `ret` of type `int **`. and this causes the error.

---

The way to resolve the problem is to use `void *`. that is one way to use **generics** in C.

Take a look at [qsort](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/qsort.c#L116) in C.

```
void Ex(void *_ret, int ret_len, int choice){
    if(choice==1){
        int *ret = (int *)_ret;              // <---- type conversion
        for(int i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            *(ret+i) = i;
        }
     } else {
        int **ret = (int **)_ret;            // <---- type conversion
        for(int i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<ret_len; j++){
                *(*(ret+i)+j) = i*j;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I had tried the void pointer *but I was missing the cast*. This answer certainly compiles and makes sense to me.  Do you really need to declare a new variable though or did you do that for clarity like the explicit cast? Why does the compiler fret if you don't cast though? It seems that if I dodnt cast and had `void * ret` then it could very well be a pointer to a pointer still

Comment: @CircArgs no, new variable declaration is not a must, just for clarity.

Comment: _I don't have to loop through malloc_ So I think `int **ret = (int **)_ret;` is incorrect.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY are you saying this loops through `malloc`? I've not let on how exactly I am allocating the memory. I just didn't want answers suggesting dynamic allocation in the scope of the function

Comment: @CircArgs Please show me how you are securing memory on the caller side.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY sure. I'm actually using LuaJIT's FFI: `ffi.new('int[10][10]')` as an example. However, would this answer not work if I had allocated it as `float * ret=malloc(sizeof(int)*10*10)`? I admit I do not know how exactly the ffi implementation works behind the scenes

Comment: @CircArgs Why is `float*`? Anyway, you can write code to test if `Ex` behaves as expected by yourself.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `float*` was a typo

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing with least change of your existing code I came up with is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Ex(int * ret, int ret_len, int choice){
    if(choice==1){
        for(int i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            *(ret+i)=i;
        }
     }else{
        for(int i=0; i<ret_len; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<ret_len; j++){
                *(ret + i*ret_len + j) = i*j;
            }
        }
     }
}

int main() {
  int anint[10][10];
  Ex(anint, 10, 2);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {printf("%d\n", anint[i][j]);}
  }
}
```

Basically, I mannually manipulate the offset within the `Ex` function. and I take the assumption that the length of the two dimensions are always the same.

A more "conventioal way" would be a true 2-dimentional array in which each element is malloc independently. Thus, the element of the first level array can be casted by force to a pointer and be dereferenced in the second level. But I am reluctant to call malloc too many times.

I hope this can solved your problem.

Comment: Can you really index into a multidimensional array as if it were 1d as in your else statement? I'm having trouble testing this as it doesnt seem to work

Comment: you can. On a Mac or Linux, `gcc aa.c`  and then  `./a.out`